# Can't dereference MutexGuard because vec doesn't implement the Copy trait

Tags: multithreading, rust

New to Rust. Trying to transfer ownership of a `Vec<Option<Box<dyn CoolTrait>>>` in a thread, but I can't dereference the MutexGuard:

```rust
fn main() {
    let cool_vec: Vec<Option<Box<dyn CoolTrait>>> = vec![];
    let vec_mx = Mutex::new(cool_vec);

    let mythread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mxguard = vec_mx.lock().unwrap();
        do_an_action(*mxguard);
    });
}
```

Compiler complains on that last line with:

```
cannot move out of dereference of MutexGuard<'_, Vec<Option<Box<dyn CoolTrait>>>
move occurs because value has type Vec<Option<Box<dyn CoolTrait>>>, which does not implement the Copy trait
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: _Trying to transfer ownership of a `Vec<_>` in a thread_ You already transferred ownership to the thread, is there any other reason to dereference `MutexGuard` ? Or do you want to have something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=02d6a76078fc93ef26d8def4fd29f8d1)?

Comment: @herpderp tell us what you want to achieve, instead of how you plan to do it

Comment: Basically, the main thread needs ownership of the vec, as does the do_an_action function in the other thread. I'm trying to pass it back and forth between the threads

Comment: Note that a bare `Mutex` is almost always useless since it can only have one owner so there is no need for locking. `Mutex` only makes sense if it is behind some kind of reference, eg. `&Mutex` (which will almost certainly need to be `'static`) or `Arc<Mutex>`.

Comment: @herpderp that can not work, `Mutex` can only hand out (mutable) references. To get an owned `Vec` out you'd have to `mem::take` the value, move it into the function... then the `main` would find itself with an empty `Vec` which wouldn't be very useful. By definition you can't have both the thread and the `main` own the same vector, you need a shared owner (an `Arc`) to actually own the thing, and mediate access (but not hand out ownership).

Comment: @herpderp I'm curious if my answer helps with your question. It just received a downvote (unfortunately without an accompanying explanation), so SO readers obviously didn't find it helpful. If it's not useful to you either, I'll just delete it.

Answer (score -1):

From the comment:

> I'm trying to pass [the vector] back and forth between the threads

To send a value to a thread, you don't need a `Mutex`, you can just move the value into the closure that the thread will execute:

```
trait CoolTrait: Send {}

fn main() {
    let cool_vec: Vec<Option<Box<dyn CoolTrait>>> = vec![];
    let mythread = thread::spawn(move || {
        do_an_action(&cool_vec);
    });
    // do other things...
    mythread.join().unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e20050bacd56a2ac8a67fa603a818b9)

Note that `CoolTrait` must require `Send` as the super-trait (or `dyn CoolTrait` needs to change to `dyn CoolTrait + Send`) in order to send the trait objects between threads.

To send the object back to the main thread once `mythread` is done, you can use the return value of the closure passed to `thread::spawn()`:

```
fn main() {
    let cool_vec: Vec<Option<Box<dyn CoolTrait>>> = vec![];
    let mythread = thread::spawn(move || {
        do_an_action(&cool_vec);
        cool_vec
    });
    // cool_vec is now owned by mythread, do other things here
    // ...
    let cool_vec = mythread.join().unwrap();
    // mythread is done and we got cool_vec back!
    // ...
}
```

To exchange values between threads without waiting for the thread to complete, you can use [channels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html).